# Using image as background for static table view with storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm creating a tabbar application without storyboards and instead created a storyboard for one of my tabs. I have a UITableViewController with a static table view. I also have it embedded in a Navigation Controller. Since it is a static table view, I have segues that point to different view controllers. I have no files linked to the table view. I want to be able to set a background image for the table view. I have tried using a UIImageView and attempting to put it behind the table view but storyboards won't let me. Any suggestions?

Image of storyboard: http://gyazo.com/b94987037a31d6164815790d90ba26d9

Comment: For creating the background image in static cell you really need to create some classes(files) and impliment the code I gave you in that class. It is not possible to create a background image in static cell without that.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to add it in your source, I think it is not possible directly in the storyboard:

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];
[tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame]; 

self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```

Comment: What source are you talking about? When I try adding it to a UITableViewController, I get an error    .frame not recognized and .background not recognized?

Comment: I just edited the source, probably now it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

This is ggrana solution, but in Swift:

```
    let imvTableBackground = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage(named: "imgBackground"))
    imvTableBackground.frame = self.tableView.frame
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imvTableBackground
```

If so, vote up his solution in Obj-C

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet that might help you. You need to add the image as the cell content. Try the following:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  cell = [CalculatorTableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:nil]; //This wil obviously depend on your subclass
  UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Yourimage.png"]];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
 }
```

Change the yourimage.png to the name of the image you are using.

Comment: How would I implement this as I just have a tableview controller in a storyboard with no files attached? No anything just the table for looks. Do I create a UITableViewController class?

Comment: In your question you said, you have a tableviewcontroller in one of the tab that is also embedded in navigation controller. You impliment the above code in cellforrowatindexpath of the tableviewcontroller class that you are trying to add a background image to its static cell.